# How to wait for an Async function to finish before doing anything?

Tags: flutter

I am using a login API to log into my app and from the response i get from the Login API, I want to call another API that will populate data on the Home Page.

However when I attempt to make the second API call and then move to home page. It moves to second page before the API is finished and gives null values. (The second API call is working properly and gives req data, just after some time)

How can i resolve this? Thank you.

My Login Page

```
import .....

class Login extends StatefulWidget{

  final void Function(UserCredentials) onSignedIn;

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {

  var response;

  //To save data from  FIRST API to shared Pref
  Future<bool> saveNamedPreference(String ID, String authid) async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString("ID", ID );
    prefs.setString("authID", authid );

    return await prefs.setBool("iDExist", true);
  }


  //
  //To save data from  SECOND API to shared Pref
  Future<bool> saveUserPreference(String name, String role) async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString("name", name);
    prefs.setString("role", role );

    return await prefs.setBool("UserExists", true);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    //SECOND API CALL 
    Future<int> saveUserDetails(String userID, String authID) async{

      getUser(userID, authID).then((value){

        final json = value;
        if(json!="Error"){
          User user = userFromJson(json);
          saveUserPreference(user.username, user.role);
          print('set the other values too ');
          return 1;
        }
        else{
          print('dint get proper json data ');
          return 0;
        }
      });

    }

    //LOGIN API 
    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
      var client = http.Client();


      var response = await client
          .post(
          Uri.encodeFull(
              '{url}'),
          body:
        {"email":"$username","password":"$password"}

      ).whenComplete(
          client.close);

      var res = json.decode(response.body);

      if(response.statusCode <200 || response.statusCode > 400){
        print("Error");
         throwError();
      }
      if(response.statusCode == 200 ){

        saveNamedPreference(res["userId"], res["id"]);;
        UserCredentials uc = userCredentialsFromJson(response.body);

//Using then so that it shifts to Home only after func completion however its not happening 
        saveUserDetails(uc.userId, uc.id).then((value){
          widget.onSignedIn(uc); //gives call back to root page to move to HOME 
        });
      }

      if (!mounted)
        return {'success': false};

      return json.decode(response.body);
    }
;

    Stack stack = Stack(
      ...... );

    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: stack
    );
  }
}
```

In my Home page, in the init method, I am accessing the values from Shared Pref (using the same async then method )and then updating the value using setState however it still gives null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move all these methods with api calls to outside of your `build` method.

Maybe the problem it's here:
`saveNamedPreference(res["userId"], res["id"]);`

You aren't awaiting until this method returns.
When you're working asynchronous methods and want to wait for the response, you need to use await.

I think this code looks much better...

```
import .....

class Login extends StatefulWidget {

  final void Function(UserCredentials) onSignedIn;

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var response;

  //To save data from  FIRST API to shared Pref
  Future<bool> saveNamedPreference(String ID, String authid) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString("ID", ID);
    prefs.setString("authID", authid);

    return await prefs.setBool("iDExist", true);
  }

  //To save data from  SECOND API to shared Pref
  Future<bool> saveUserPreference(String name, String role) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString("name", name);
    prefs.setString("role", role);

    return await prefs.setBool("UserExists", true);
  }

  //SECOND API CALL 
  Future<int> saveUserDetails(String userID, String authID) async {
    final json = await getUser(userID, authID);

    if (json != "Error") {
      User user = userFromJson(json);
      saveUserPreference(user.username, user.role);
      print('set the other values too ');
      return 1;
    } else {
      print('dint get proper json data ');
      return 0;
    }
  }

  //LOGIN API 
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
    var client = http.Client();

    var response = await client
        .post(
        Uri.encodeFull('{url}'),
        body: {"email": "$username", "password": "$password"}
    );

    var res = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400) {
      print("Error");
      throwError();
    }

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await saveNamedPreference(res["userId"], res["id"]);
      UserCredentials uc = userCredentialsFromJson(response.body);

      //Using then so that it shifts to Home only after func completion however its not happening 
      await saveUserDetails(uc.userId, uc.id);
      widget.onSignedIn(uc); //gives call back to root page to move to HOME
    }

    if (!mounted) {
      return {'success': false};
    }

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: _buildStack(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStack(){
    return Stack(
      ......
    );
  }
}
```